# bootstrap-vue carousel slides not updating after adding new image

Tags: vue.js, carousel, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use bootstrap-vue b-carousel component adding dynamic images to the carousel does not update the carousel content. Here is my test:

```
<b-carousel v-model="active" fade :interval="1000" :id="'carousel' + items.length" indicators controls clajss="picture-viewer-carousbel">
       <b-carousel-slide v-for="(item,index) in items" :id="'slideId'+index" :key="'slideId'+index" :img-src="item" img-width="100%">
       </b-carousel-slide>
     </b-carousel>
```

And here is the code part

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function () {
    return {
      active: 0,
      items: ['https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=10']
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.items.push('https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=12')
  }
}
```

I am expecting the carousel to display 2 images but it isn't it only displays one image, even though the reactivity is working correctly because the id of the carousel which takes into account the number of slides is correct (:id="'carousel' + items.length") is 'carousel2'. It would be 'carousel1' if the reactivity would not be working.

Not sure what and if I am doing something wrong but any help is welcome

Thanks

Pat

```
package.json

{
  "name": "bootstrapvue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^6.0.0-beta2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.0.0-beta2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.0.0-beta2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.5",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.14.0",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^4.41.2",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-animation": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-data-tools": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-dateinputs": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-dropdowns": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-grid": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-inputs": "^2.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-vue-intl": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.18.1",
    "interactjs": "^1.10.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.1",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "sortablejs": "^1.14.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-fontawesome": "0.0.2",
    "vue-resizable": "^2.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.9",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.42.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with more information about your template and package versions? I created an example based on your code and it works fine

Comment: Example: https://codepen.io/tymoteuszlao/pen/bGvBQQY

Comment: That is indeed strange

I have added my versions in the code above

Comment: Do you receive any error or a warning in the console?

Comment: unfortunately none

Comment: Hello, i'm having the same issue, have you found the solution ?